# Using Excel with VBA to copy and rename tables

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, I've got VBA to prompt for a string name for a new worksheet name and I then use that name to update/append a table of worksheet names, copy an existing template worksheet, rename the newly created worksheet. All that works with no issue.

The problem I'm running into now is that I want to rename a table that is copied over from the template. Let's say on the template sheet, the table name is tblTemplate. When the template worksheet is copied, the table within the new worksheet comes with a sequential number suffix. So using the previous example, the new table name is something like tblTemplate012. This suffix is always increasing, even if I delete the worksheet and and copy from the template. The new table name is then tblTemplate013. This makes it challenging to select that table without knowing what the sequential number will be the next time it's copied.

Is there a way to select/modify the table name without knowing the table number suffix? Does listObjects allow for some sort of fuzzy match or is that the wrong way to go about it?

Comment: Does that sheet contain one table, or multiple?

Comment: Only one table.

Comment: Then just refer to it by index: `.ListObjects(1)`.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, I guess I need to learn more abut the .ListObjects modifier. I wasn't aware you could just call it by index.

Comment: BigBen - You the real MVP. That said, what if the worksheet has multiple tables etc... is there an easy way to identify the index number?

Comment: Assuming the table names are significantly different, you could loop through all the `ListObjects` in the sheet and check if their `.Name Like "tempTable*"` or similar

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user BigBen, since there's only one table in my worksheet, I can just refer to it by its ListObjects index, which will be 1. So then I can use something like:

.ListObjects(1).Name to update the name of the new table.